# Replenishing Lives ater 30 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, nsdate, nstimer

I'm coding a game in `Spritekit`. After a user loses my game, I want to create a way for the user's lives to replenish after 30 minutes
I created an integer (called Lives) and every time the user loses the game it subtracts 1 from the integer
I just don't know how to replenish the user's lives after 30 minutes has passed. I wrote the following code in an `NSObject` Helper Class but it's not working.

```
-(void)ReplenishLives{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval oldDateTimeInterval = [now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval thirtyMinutes = 60 * 30;
    if (oldDateTimeInterval > thirtyMinutes) {
        Lives = 5;
    }
}

-(void)CheckTime{
    LifeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(ReplenishLives) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: You need to store the initial (old) oldDateTimeInterval. In your current form you keep subtracted the current 'old' from the current time. Look into using NSUserDefaults to store the initial time value and compare that to the current one.

Answer (score 1):

One major issue is that you're calculating `oldDateTimeInterval` to be something other than the last time the user lost (specifically, you're setting it equal to the time interval between now and January 1, 2001, at 12:00 a.m. GMT). `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` gives you the time since January 1, 2001, at 12:00 a.m. GMT, which is not what you want.

I would recommend using `NSLog()` to log your `oldDateTimeInterval` and make sure it's functioning the way you want it to. This will print whatever you put inside of it in the console. For example:

```
NSLog(@"old time interval %f", oldDateTimeInterval);
```

Then, what you'll likely want to do is save an `NSDate` variable (maybe in `NSUserDefaults`) that will hold the last time the user lost your game. You can then make your comparisons from that date instead of the irrelevant one you are using now.

Comment: I tried this but the NSLog is not printing the time interval when I run the app.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in that method to make sure that code is actually being executed? NSLog will never fail you, so there's something else going on there.